# Does a single core CPU allow only parallel execution?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

In the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635572/can-multiple-os-processes-run-in-parallel-on-multicore-cpu) a guy said that "a single core CPU can allow only parallel execution"

> "So a multi-core CPU allows not only parallel but also concurrent execution of processes. On the other hand, a single core CPU can allow only parallel execution. No concurrency is there in single core machines."

Shouldn't it actually allow only *concurrent* execution instead?
If it's a single core CPU, how can it execute operations in parallel?
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, they probably got it the other way around. Parallel: Two executions at the same time. Concurrent: Two executions at interleaved times.

Comment: It is wrong either way. A core with simultaneous multithreading can run multiple threads at the same time. Even just fine-grained multithreading is arguably executing multiple threads at the same time (different threads in different pipeline stages but multiple threads active in the core at the same time). From an OS perspective switch-on-event multithreading provides execution of multiple threads within a time slice on a single core even if switches drain the pipeline.